# How to extend a button in 2 columns in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want to extend a button in a grid pane to make it looks like this:

[Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8uj3.png)

Mine looks like this for the moment...

[My Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldcZj.png)

This is part of my code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAC"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons_white"
            android:text="AC"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMasMenos"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"

            android:background="@drawable/buttons_white"
            android:text="+/-"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />
```

Im very new in android studio, thank you in advance

Comment: So, which of these two buttons that you provided in the snippet code is malfunctioning? And I assume the one in red in the screenshot is the button you're talking about, isn't it?

Comment: I would like to change the position of the red button and extend the one with the 0

Comment: So, none of the buttons you provided in the snippet code is required to be corrected or changed. You might want to add the buttons you need help with the way you have them in your file so we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding stretch column in your table layout [example here](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/tablelayout).